# close the gap in the bottom of a relativelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

After creating a relative layout on rendering it, I observed that there is space below the layout that is not needful. I have ensured that all the height of the elements used has a wrap_content attribute as the specification parameter for the height.
Below is the snippet

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#338FD8D8">

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/banner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:padding="3px"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:padding="3px"
                    android:layout_marginRight="100px"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>
            </LinearLayout>

         </RelativeLayout>
```

My challenge is how can I close the gaps that occurs inside the layout below the the last content

Comment: Why don't you make `layout_height=match_parent` for the outermost `RelativeLayout`? That will surely fill your gap

Comment: it did not work

Comment: 'it did not work' is not really descriptive. Did you still have the gap? Did you run into a different layout issue? Sharing some screenshots might help too

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but you can change your RelativeLayout height to

> android:layout_height="match_parent"

Also have a look at [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows) for `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.

Hope this helps.